# Optimizing code that reads a JSON file and a CSV file and compares them and outputs to a file

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm

I have written this code that reads a JSON and CSV files compares them and outputs to a text file This output file will contains the association that my program has created in the following format
<CSV_SENSOR_ID>:<JSON_SENSOR_ID>. If a flying object was only picked up by one of the sensors, the
other sensor’s ID should be reported as -1. If the distance between two readings is below 100 then we can assume that both IDs match.

I understand that the bulk of my code is in the checkJSON function and the distance calculations, I was wondering if anyone has ideas to improve the speed and space requirements for this program and task!

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
//using namespace std;


std::string filenameA = "input.csv";
std::string filenameB = "input.json";


    /*
     * utlity function that converts degrees to radians
     * code 
     * @param degree: angle in degrees
     */
long double toRadians(const long double degree) 
{ 
    // cmath library in C++  
    // defines the constant 
    // M_PI as the value of 
    // pi accurate to 1e-30 
    long double one_deg = (M_PI) / 180; 
    return (one_deg * degree); 
} 

 /**
     * function that calculates the distance give longitudes and latitudes
     * code obtained from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-distance-two-points-earth/
     */  

long double distance(long double lat1, long double long1,  
                     long double lat2, long double long2) 
{ 
    // Convert the latitudes  
    // and longitudes 
    // from degree to radians. 
    lat1 = toRadians(lat1); 
    long1 = toRadians(long1); 
    lat2 = toRadians(lat2); 
    long2 = toRadians(long2); 
      
    // Haversine Formula 
    long double dlong = long2 - long1; 
    long double dlat = lat2 - lat1; 
  
    long double ans = pow(sin(dlat / 2), 2) +  
                          cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) *  
                          pow(sin(dlong / 2), 2); 
  
    ans = 2 * asin(sqrt(ans)); 
  
    // Radius of Earth in  
    // Kilometers, R = 6371 
    // Use R = 3956 for miles 
    long double R = 6371; 
      
    // Calculate the result 
    ans = ans * R*1000; //answer in metres
  
    return ans; 
} 


/*
 * creating a structure of type SensorData that 
 * holds the values for the ID, latitude and longitude
 */
struct SensorData {
    int id;
    std::string latitude;
    std::string longitude;
};

std::vector<SensorData> csvData; //creating an array of type sensor data
std::vector<std::string> outputData; // creating an output dataArray that is going to be used to write to file


/**
 * function that reads the CSV file and 
 * stores the data read into the csvData array
 * 
 * @param filename: the name of the input file that is going to be reads
 */
void readCSV(std::string filename){
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    std::string input;
    std::getline(file, input);
    while(std::getline(file, input)){
        std::stringstream ss(input);
        std::vector<std::string> data;
        while(ss.good()){
            std::string sub;
            std::getline(ss, sub, ',');
            data.push_back(sub);
        }
        if(data.size() == 3) {
            SensorData locData = {std::stoi(data[0]), data[1], data[2]};
            csvData.push_back(locData);
        }
    }
}


/**
 * function that reads the JSON file and 
 * compares the longitude and latitude to the CSV file and places the matching IDs in an output vector 
 * also matches the flying objects detected by only the JSON "sensor" to -1.
 * @param filename: the name of the input file that is going to be reads
 */
void checkJSON(std::string filename){
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    while(file){
        std::string input;
        std::getline(file, input, '}');
        if(input.size() < 6)
            continue;
        std::stringstream ss(input.substr(6));
        std::vector<std::string> data;
        while(ss.good()){
            std::string sub;
            std::getline(ss, sub, ',');
            sub = sub.substr(sub.find_first_not_of(" \t\n\r\v\f"));
            if(sub[1] == 'I')
                data.push_back(sub.substr(7, sub.size() - 8));
            else if(sub[2] == 'a')
                data.push_back(sub.substr(12, sub.size() - 1));
            else
                data.push_back(sub.substr(13, sub.size() - 1));
        }
        bool found = false;
        for(auto i = csvData.begin(); i != csvData.end(); ++i){
            if((data[1] == i->latitude && data[2] == i->longitude) || distance(stold(data[1]), stold(data[2]), stold(i->latitude), stold(i->longitude))<=100)
            {
                std::string output = std::to_string(i->id);
                output += ":";
                output += data[0];
                output += "\n";
                outputData.push_back(output);
                csvData.erase(i);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found){
            std::string output = "-1:";
            output += data[0];
            output += "\n";
            outputData.push_back(output);
        }
    }
    file.close();
}


/**
 * function that writes to an output text file. It also 
 * matches flying objects picked up by only the CSV "sensor" file to -1.
 */
void writeFile(){
    std::string output = "output";
    output += filenameA[7];
    output += ".txt";
    std::ofstream file(output);
    if (!file)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file for writing" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    for(auto i : outputData){
        std::cout << i;
        file << i;
    }
    if(csvData.size() != 0){
        for(auto i : csvData){
            std::string output = std::to_string(i.id);
            output += ":-1\n";
            std::cout << output;
            file << output;
        }
    }
    file.close();
}

 


int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    if(argc != 1 && argc != 3){
        std::cerr << "Invalid arguments" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    if(argc == 3){
        filenameA = argv[1];
        filenameB = argv[2];
    }
    readCSV(filenameA);
    checkJSON(filenameB);
    writeFile();
   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## General advice

### Use proper types

One of the best things you can do to make C++ code better and—*usually*—faster (either compiling faster, running faster, or both) is to make proper types. C++ is a strongly-typed language, probably *the* most strongly-type language in popular use. Lean into that. Take advantage of it. Reap the rewards.

For example…

Your program is working a lot with numbers. All kinds of numbers, which can easily get mixed up. For this, it might be a good idea to use a units library. The state of the art is [mp-units](https://mpusz.github.io/units/). (There’s also [Boost.Units](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_units.html) if you’re already using Boost.)

To see why a units library can help, look at this bit of your code:

```
// Radius of Earth in  
// Kilometers, R = 6371 
// Use R = 3956 for miles 
long double R = 6371; 
  
// Calculate the result 
ans = ans * R*1000; //answer in metres
```

If someone who actually wants the result in US customary units, if they make the mistake of merely replacing `long double R = 6371;` with `long double R = 3956;`… they’re going to get the answer in “milli-miles”.

With a units library, you could define your constants like so:

```
#include <units/physical/si/si.h>
#include <units/physical/si/us/us.h>

using namespace units::physical::si::literals;

constexpr auto radius_of_earth = 6371_q_km;
// if someone would rather work with us units, then they could just replace
// the above line with:
constexpr auto radius_of_earth = 3956_q_mi_us;
// and the program would still work correctly.
```

But even without a units library, using proper types could net you *massive* gains in speed, safety, and flexibility.

One place where you would probably see a lot of gains is your `SensorData` type. As it’s currently written, you keep the ID as an `int`… but the latitude and longitude as strings. Then in `checkJSON()`, you first try a string comparison which… not a great idea, really… and then fallback on converting everything to `long double` to do the distance comparison. The upshot of this is that `SensorData` is a *lot* bigger than it needs to be (strings are *much* bigger than `long double`s on any platform I’ve ever heard of), and a *lot* slower when comparing with other data (string comparisons are a *lot* slower than comparing doubles—even with an epsilon (more on that shortly)).

So if you made a *proper* class for the sensor data:

```
class SensorData
{
    int id;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    // proper inserter function:
    friend auto operator>>(std::istream& in, SensorData& data) -> std::istream&
    {
        auto temp = sensor_data{};
        auto comma = char{};

        in >> temp.id;
        in >> comma; // optional: confirm that comma is a comma
                     // even better, you could write a manipulator that
                     // checks for a comma, then ignores it
        in >> temp.d1;
        in >> comma;
        in >> temp.d2;

        // ignore rest of line (which should be nothing but a newline char)
        // if you want, you can confirm this, or just assume it's always
        // true and skip this line
        if (in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'))
            // only if the input isn't bad or fail, save the result
            data = std::move(temp);

        return in;
    }
};
```

Now, watch what that does to just `readCSV()` for example:

```
auto readCSV(std::filesystem::path const& path)
{
    auto file = std::ifstream{path};
    
    // you should usually, if not always, do this
    file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

    // turn off locale stuff so numbers parse properly
    // you should *always* do this unless you want locale stuff
    file.imbue(std::locale::classic());

    // Looks like we need to ignore one line (a header line?)
    file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    return std::vector(
        std::istream_iterator<SensorData>{file},
        std::istream_iterator<SensorData>{}
    );
}
```

Yup, that’s it. That’s literally it. And not only will your data vector be *much* smaller—possibly nearly a third of the size—the whole read function will probably be *hundreds*, if not ***THOUSANDS*** of times faster due to not needing a new string stream and vector for each data point. In addition, everything else involving the CSV data will be faster too, because, since each data point is now so much smaller, more of them will fit in cache.

And, really, you should have types for the IDs, too, so they don't get fuggered up when being printed. (For example, you wouldn’t want IDs converted to hex… that makes no sense.) But for a tiny, one-off program, it’s probably not worth it.

I always teach this mantra to my students: In C++, if you get the *types* right, everything else just magically falls into place. It’s worth it.

### Don’t use `long double`

`long double` is some bullshit. There, I said it.

On any platform you’re likely to be running this code on, `double` will give you ~15–16 digits of precision, while `long double` *MAY* (more on that in a sec) give you ~19 (at most ~34 on, like 64-bit ARM). Are you *really* in a situation where you absolutely cannot tolerate an error of 0.00000000000001… but an error of 0.000000000000000001 is okay? I mean, are you seriously concerned about 0.00000000000001°… which is roughly 0.000000000111 metres, or 111 *pico*metres *in the worst case*? Are you trying to distinguish between individual atoms at the equator?

Because, here’s the thing: the *cost* of those extra 3–4 digits of precision is *high*. Not only are you paying for 2 more bytes *per value*, you’re often also paying for extra padding bytes for alignment to keep `double`s on 64-bit address boundaries. Yikes. All that extra space costs big by bumping data out of cache.

Also, the larger size of `long double` means it’s harder for them to be vectorized. You may shrug at the *size* difference—`double`s are 8 bytes, `long doubles` are 10, and meh, what’s 2 piddly bytes… but simple operations like adding two values can be like 4 or 8 times faster with `double`s than with `long double`s due to better vectorization. SSE can work with 2 `double`s at a time, AVX can do 4, and AVX-512 can do 8. For example, with AVX, those 4 lines at the start of `distance()` can basically be done simultaneously. Even old-school SSE can do two at a time.

In fact, and this may come as a shock to you, if you’re using MSVC… then there *is* no `long double`. [`long double` just maps to `double`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=msvc-160). Why? Because `long double` doesn’t work with SSE. (GCC still uses an 80-bit `long double`, though.)

Just use `double`. Not only is it less typing, it’s smaller, faster, and you may already be using it anyway.

## Code review

```
std::string filenameA = "input.csv";
std::string filenameB = "input.json";
```

Your code uses several globals, which is never a great idea, and in this case, there are no real benefits. These variables could be local to `main()`.

Also, these are paths. Rather than using naked strings, you should use the proper type: `std::filesystem::path`.

```
long double toRadians(const long double degree) 
{ 
    // cmath library in C++  
    // defines the constant 
    // M_PI as the value of 
    // pi accurate to 1e-30 
    long double one_deg = (M_PI) / 180; 
    return (one_deg * degree); 
}
```

No, sorry, the `<cmath>` library does no such thing. `M_PI` is not part of C++ (or C for that matter), though it’s a common extension. And as for it being accurate to 30 decimal places… that’s just absurd. GCC only defines it with ~20 digits (which is already way more digits than necessary).

Math constants are available in C++20. If you have a recent compiler, you can include `<numbers>`, and then π is `std::numbers::pi`.

If you don’t have C++20, then you have to do things the bad old way:

```
#ifndef M_PI
#   define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif
```

Either way, you should use a `constexpr` constant:

```
auto toRadians(double degrees)
{
    constexpr auto degrees_to_radians = std::numbers::pi / 180.0;

    return degrees * degress_to_radians;
}
```

That constant isn’t really useful outside of that function, so you might as well keep it there.

In `distance()`:

```
long double distance(long double lat1, long double long1,  
                     long double lat2, long double long2) 
{ 
    // Convert the latitudes  
    // and longitudes 
    // from degree to radians. 
    lat1 = toRadians(lat1); 
    long1 = toRadians(long1); 
    lat2 = toRadians(lat2); 
    long2 = toRadians(long2); 
      
    // Haversine Formula 
    long double dlong = long2 - long1; 
    long double dlat = lat2 - lat1; 
  
    long double ans = pow(sin(dlat / 2), 2) +  
                          cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) *  
                          pow(sin(dlong / 2), 2); 
  
    ans = 2 * asin(sqrt(ans)); 
  
    // Radius of Earth in  
    // Kilometers, R = 6371 
    // Use R = 3956 for miles 
    long double R = 6371; 
      
    // Calculate the result 
    ans = ans * R*1000; //answer in metres
  
    return ans; 
}
```

You’re missing *several* `std::` for all the math functions.

I don’t recommend relying on operator precedence for things to work. So when calculating `ans`, you probably want to put some parentheses around the last three terms.

As for the constant `R`, you should never use all uppercase names for anything but preprocessor definitions. In any case, the radius of the Earth is a useful constant that might change (you might make it more precise, for example). For that reason, you should probably pull it out of the function and give it a proper name:

```
constexpr auto mean_radius_of_earth = 6371.0; // radius of Earth in km
```

Now, if you’re going to work in one unit, and you’re not using a units library, you’re better off sticking to that one unit. You want the distance in metres, so:

```
constexpr auto mean_radius_of_earth = 6'371'008.8 ; // radius of Earth in m
```

If you want to use miles or feet or whatever instead, you just need to change this one constant.

```
/*
 * creating a structure of type SensorData that 
 * holds the values for the ID, latitude and longitude
 */
struct SensorData {
    int id;
    std::string latitude;
    std::string longitude;
};

std::vector<SensorData> csvData; //creating an array of type sensor data
std::vector<std::string> outputData; // creating an output dataArray that is going to be used to write to file
```

I’ve already shown how you can improve `SensorData`, and both of those globals shouldn’t be globals.

```
void readCSV(std::string filename){
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    std::string input;
    std::getline(file, input);
    while(std::getline(file, input)){
        std::stringstream ss(input);
        std::vector<std::string> data;
        while(ss.good()){
            std::string sub;
            std::getline(ss, sub, ',');
            data.push_back(sub);
        }
        if(data.size() == 3) {
            SensorData locData = {std::stoi(data[0]), data[1], data[2]};
            csvData.push_back(locData);
        }
    }
}
```

I’ve already shown how `readCSV()` can be improved if you improve `SensorData`, but I’ll dig into this function anyway.

First, you don’t want to be taking the function argument by value. That creates a copy of the string… and there’s no point. If you’re just going to be looking at its value, you should take the argument by `const&`. (It won’t make a practical difference, because most likely your filenames are short enough for the small string optimization, and anyway it’s just one copy in the whole program, so it won’t matter.)

The first thing you do in the function is create the input stream… good. And then you create a string to hold the current line… also good, though you should probably give this a better name. Like `line`, because that’s what it is. Then you get a line and discard it… no problem, I guess it’s a header line, right? Then you start the loop, checking the state of the file after each `getline()`… all good.

Inside the loop is where your troubles begin. First you create a string stream… not great, but… well, I mean, you need a fresh string stream each loop iteration, so, meh. (You should also imbue the classic locale, because you’re parsing numbers. But that’s no big deal either.)

However, the *next* line creates a vector… *in every loop iteration*. *THAT* is going to slow you down. And it’s especially wasteful because you reuse the vector over and over, and it will (should!) be the same size every time. By putting the vector inside the loop, you’re paying for reallocation over and over and over. Worse, you’re not even using the fact that you know it will (should!) be 3 elements long, and pre-allocating, so it’s *possible* (though not likely) that each call to `push_back()`—which is happening 3 times *per loop*—is allocating memory.

So let’s start by pulling the vector out of the loop… and give it a better name than “data”:

```
auto readCSV(std::filesystem::path const& path)
{
    std::vector<SensorData> csv_data;

    std::ifstream file{path};
    file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> line_parts;
    line_parts.reserve(3); // we expect 3 parts on each line

    // skip the header line?
    std::getline(file, line);

    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        std::istringstream ss{line};
        ss.imbue(std::locale::classic());

        // ... [snip] ...

        // clear the line parts for the next loop iteration
        // this shouldn't actually free the memory, though, so it can be
        // reused
        line_parts.clear()
    }

    return csv_data;
}
```

Now the next thing you do is read “lines” from the string stream, using commas as the “end-of-line” delimiter, and store them in the `line_part` vector. But that requires another string, which is being created again and again each time through the loop. *Hopefully* each string is small enough that it doesn’t require allocation… but I don’t know what your data looks like. To be safe, you should pull the string out of the loop:

```
auto readCSV(std::filesystem::path const& path)
{
    std::vector<SensorData> csv_data;

    std::ifstream file{path};
    file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

    std::string line;
    std::string line_part;
    std::vector<std::string> line_parts;
    line_parts.reserve(3);

    // skip the header line?
    std::getline(file, line);

    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        std::istringstream ss{line};
        ss.imbue(std::locale::classic());

        while (std::getline(ss, line_part, ','))
            line_parts.push_back(line_part); // !!!

        // ... [snip] ...

        line_parts.clear()
    }

    return csv_data;
}
```

But there’s still a problem. On that line marked with `!!!`, you’re *copying* `line_part` into `line_parts` every time. You *could* change that to a move, but… then we lose all the benefits of having `line_part` outside of the loop; the memory is no longer being re-used each time through the loop, because we’re moving it away each time, so each new time through it has to be re-allocated.

Let’s rethink.

Here’s an interesting idea. What if we tried reading each line part *directly* into the `line_parts` vector. The catch is, we’d need one extra element in order to account for that last, failed read. But that’s okay, because if all the memory is allocated at the start, it costs us nothing to have one extra string there each loop.

So we could do this:

```
auto readCSV(std::filesystem::path const& path)
{
    std::vector<SensorData> csv_data;

    std::ifstream file{path};
    file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> line_parts;
    line_parts.reserve(4); // expect 3 parts + 1 space for the last attempted read

    // skip the header line?
    std::getline(file, line);

    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        std::istringstream ss{line};
        ss.imbue(std::locale::classic());

        while (true)
        {
            // make space for the next part
            //
            // so long as this loop is run no more than 4 times, it should
            // never allocate, because we reserved 4 (3 + 1) spaces
            line_parts.emplace_back();

            // try to read a part
            if (not std::getline(ss, line_parts.back(), ','))
            {
                // failed to read a part, so remove the space we made, and
                // then quit the loop
                line_parts.pop_back();

                break;
            }
        }

        // ... [snip] ...

        line_parts.clear()
    }

    return csv_data;
}
```

Not bad! Now all you need to do is parse what was read:

```
auto readCSV(std::filesystem::path const& path)
{
    std::vector<SensorData> csv_data;

    std::ifstream file{path};
    file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> line_parts;
    line_parts.reserve(4);

    // skip the header line?
    std::getline(file, line);

    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        std::istringstream ss{line};
        ss.imbue(std::locale::classic());

        while (true)
        {
            line_parts.emplace_back();

            if (not std::getline(ss, line_parts.back(), ','))
            {
                line_parts.pop_back();

                break;
            }
        }

        if (line_parts.size() == 3)
        {
            csv_data.emplace_back(
                std::stoi(line_parts[0]),
                std::stod(line_parts[1]),
                std::stod(line_parts[2]));
        }
        else
        {
            // maybe throw an exception? to detect malformed data?
            throw std::runtime_error{"malformed CSV line: " + line};
        }

        line_parts.clear()
    }

    return csv_data;
}
```

This isn’t bad already. With most of the variables hoisted outside the loop, memory can be reused from one loop iteration to the next. That alone should make this function *MUCH* faster.

Can we do even better?

Maybe!

Do we really need to put the three parts of each line in a vector? What if we parsed each one as we went along?

```
// IOstreams manipulator
class ignore_char
{
    char _c;

public:
    explicit constexpr ignore_char(char c) noexcept : _c{c} {}

    friend auto operator>>(std::istream& in, ignore_char ic) -> std::istream&
    {
        // read in one character as a formatted input read
        if (auto c = char{}; in >> c)
        {
            // if the char read isn't what was expected, signal failure
            if (c != ic._c)
                in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        }
    
        return in;
    }
};

auto readCSV(std::filesystem::path const& path)
{
    std::vector<SensorData> csv_data;

    std::ifstream file{path};
    file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

    std::string line;

    // skip the header line?
    std::getline(file, line);

    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        std::istringstream ss{line};
        ss.imbue(std::locale::classic());

        auto id = int{};
        auto latitude  = double{};
        auto longitude = double{};

        ss >> id >> ignore_char(',')
            >> latitude >> ignore_char(',')
            >> longitude;

        // the rest of ss should be empty
        // if you want, you can confirm, maybe via another manipulator

        // if all the reads above were good, then save the data point
        if (ss)
        {
            csv_data.emplace_back(id, latitude, longitude);
        }
        else
        {
            // maybe throw an exception? to detect malformed data?
            throw std::runtime_error{"malformed CSV line: " + line};
        }
    }

    return csv_data;
}
```

But once you’ve done that, you don’t really need the string stream:

```
auto readCSV(std::filesystem::path const& path)
{
    std::vector<SensorData> csv_data;

    std::ifstream file{path};
    file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
    file.imbue(std::locale::classic());

    // skip the header line?
    file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    auto id = int{};
    auto latitude  = double{};
    auto longitude = double{};

    while (file >> id >> ignore_char(',') >> latitude >> ignore_char(',') >> longitude)
    {
        csv_data.emplace_back(id, latitude, longitude);
    }

    // you can check if file.eof() is true, to make sure everything was read
    // and if not, throw an error

    return csv_data;
}
```

Which is basically the same code as the version from earlier, where `SensorData` had its own extractor function.

The next function is `checkJSON()`, and it’s a whopper. It does at least 3 things:

1. It loops through the file, and for each block of JSON data:

   1. It parses the block, basically, `SensorData`.
   2. It searches `csvData` for a matching object.

      - If a match is found:

        1. It records the matched pair of IDs.
        2. It removes the matched item from `csvData`
      - Otherwise:

        1. It records the unmatched ID.

That’s a lot of work for one function, so one of the first things you need to do to bring this function under control is break some of this business out into other functions.

To start with, let’s extract the parsing.

```
auto parse_json_sensor_data(std::istream& in, sensor_data& data) -> std::istream&
{
    // basically, everything between:
    
    // std::string input;
    // std::getline(file, input, '}');
    // ...
    // 
    //     else
    //         data.push_back(sub.substr(13, sub.size() - 1));
    // }

    // and then:
    
    // data.id = std::stoi(data[0]);
    // data.latitude = std::stod(data[1]);
    // data.longitude = std::stod(data[2]);
    //
    // return in;
}

auto checkJSON(std::filesystem::path const& path)
{
    auto file = std::ifstream{path};
    file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

    auto data = sensor_data{};
    while (parse_json_sensor_data(file, data))
    {
        // ... [snip] ...
    }
}
```

Now I didn’t actually fill in `parse_json_sensor_data()`, because I can’t. You didn’t give any information about the file format. I might be able to reverse engineer parts of it from your existing code… but that would only give me an incomplete picture, and I wouldn’t be able to offer any suggestions for improving the algorithm, because I would only have the algorithm… not the data. All I could do is suggest ways to make the existing algorithm prettier; without knowing what the data looks like, I have no idea if there’s a better algorithm, or even if the existing code is wrong.

So I can’t help you with the parsing. But hopefully you can take some of the tips for parsing the CSV and apply them, such as: avoid that vector of strings, and try parsing directly from the stream rather than creating a separate string stream and parsing from that. In any case, now that the JSON parsing is its own function, you can optimize the hell of out that separately from the rest of `checkJSON()`.

Anywho, once you’ve got the data parsed, you need to find if it’s in `csvData`. Okay, first of all, you shouldn’t use a global for this, so you should add an argument to the function:

```
auto checkJSON(std::filesystem::path const& path, std::vector<SensorData> csvData)
{
    auto file = std::ifstream{path};
    file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

    auto data = sensor_data{};
    while (parse_json_sensor_data(file, data))
    {
        // ... [snip] ...
    }
}
```

Note we can take it by value because we’re not just reading it, we’re also modifying it.

Now, you have a bug in your code:

```
for(auto i = csvData.begin(); i != csvData.end(); ++i){
    // ... [snip] ...
    csvData.erase(i);
    // ... [snip] ...
}
```

Never, ever modify a container while iterating over it. In this case, when you erase the element, you invalidate the iterators… which means your whole loop is now borked. You probably got lucky because your stdlib’s vector iterators are ultimately just simple pointers, and erasing doesn’t reallocate, so it just *appears* to work. On the other hand… it might be skipping data! Have you checked?

Let’s think about what’s really going on here. You have two containers: `csvData` and `outputData`. You want to find an element in `csvData`, and *if* you find it, remove it (after taking its data and put it in `outputData`. If you *don’t* find it, you just want to put other data in `outputData`.

What this sounds like is `std::remove_if()` (plus you need to use [the erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom)):

```
csvData.erase(
    std::remove_if(csvData.begin(), csvData.end(),
        [&json_data, &output](auto&& csv_data)
        {
            if ((data[1] == i->latitude && // etc.... (will fix shortly)
            {
                // add csv_data.id and json_data.id to output
                return true; // remove the item from csvData
            }
            else
            {
                // add -1 and json_data.id to output
                return false; // DON'T remove the item from csvData
            }
        }),
    csvData.end()
);
```

Now, the way you check the distance is like this:

```
(data[1] == i->latitude && data[2] == i->longitude) || distance(stold(data[1]), stold(data[2]), stold(i->latitude), stold(i->longitude))<=100
```

Now, comparing strings is… not a great idea. String comparisons are *SLOW*, compared to `double` comparisons. If you’ve converted `SensorData` to use `double`s instead of strings, then you should already see a *significant* speedup.

*HOWEVER*, you shouldn’t really compare floating-point numbers with `==`. Instead, you should use an epsilon. Basically, you take the two numbers, and subtract them, and if the absolute value of their difference is greater than your epsilon, they are not equal. For example:

```
constexpr auto epsilon = 0.0000001; // seven decimal places of accuracy should be okay

auto values_are_equal(double v1, double v2)
{
    return std::abs(v1 - v2) < epsilon;
}
```

So now the test is:

```
constexpr auto min_distance = 100.0;

if ((values_are_equal(csv_data.latitude, json_data.latitude) and values_are_equal(csv_data.longitude, json_data.longitude))
    or distance(csv_data.latitude, csv_data.longitude, json_data.latitude, json_data.longitude) <= min_distance)
```

And of course you could save some typing by using functions to make all that much shorter.

All this should make `checkJSON()` thousands of times faster.

But… maybe we can do better!

## Alternative design

Okay, let's start with getting the types right. First we want a type representing the ID and position data that’s being read from both the CSV and JSON files:

```
struct sensor_data
{
    int id;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    // should really use std::expected instead of std::optional... but don't
    // have that yet.
    static auto read_csv_format(std::istream& in) -> std::optional<sensor_data>;
    static auto read_json_format(std::istream& in) -> std::optional<sensor_data>;
};

auto sensor_data::read_csv_format(std::istream& in) -> std::optional<sensor_data>
{
    auto id = int{};
    auto latitude  = double{};
    auto longitude = double{};

    if (file >> id >> ignore_char(',') >> latitude >> ignore_char(',') >> longitude)
        return sensor_data{id, latitude, longitude};
    else
        return std::nullopt;
}

auto sensor_data::read_json_format(std::istream& in) -> std::optional<sensor_data>
{
    // i don't know how to write this function
}
```

Now, what you currently do is read all the CSV data into a vector… then read all the JSON data in, comparing it to the CSV data as you go, and so on. The final result you want is a pair of IDs. What if we skip the middleman. You don’t really need that vector of CSV data. It’s not the final result you want. What if, instead, we made a type for the final data:

```
struct result_t
{
    int csv_id = -1;
    int json_id = -1;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
}
```

Now when you read in the CSV data, you save it in a vector of `result_t`:

```
auto read_csv_data(std::filesystem::path const& path)
{
    auto file = std::ifstream{path};
    file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
    file.imbue(std::locale::classic());

    // header line?
    file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    auto data = std::vector<result_t>{};

    while (true)
    {
        if (auto [ok, d] = sensor_data::read_csv_format(file); ok)
            data.emplace_back({.csv_id = d.id, .latitude = d.latitude, .longitude = d.longitude});
        else
            break;
    }

    return data;
}
```

So, after calling this function, you have a vector of entries, where each entry has a `csv_id`, `latitude`, and `longitude`, and a `json_id` of `-1`.

Now you pass that data into the JSON function:

```
auto read_json_data(std::filesystem::path const& path, std::vector<result_t> result_data)
{
    auto file = std::ifstream{path};
    file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
    file.imbue(std::locale::classic());

    while (true)
    {
        if (auto [ok, d] = sensor_data::read_json_format(file); ok)
        {
            auto is_close = [&d](auto&& csv_data)
            {
                return (values_are_equal(csv_data.latitude, d.latitude) and values_are_equal(csv_data.longitude, d.longitude))
                    or distance(csv_data.latitude, csv_data.longitude, d.latitude, d.longitude) <= min_distance;
            }

            // If you find a data point in the existing result_data that is
            // close, then set its json_id. Since the csv_id is already set,
            // that means the entry now has both IDs set.
            //
            // Otherwise, if you don't find one, add the new json data with
            // a csv_id of -1.

            if (auto p = std::find_if(result_data.begin(), result_data.end(), is_close); p != result_data.end())
                p->json_id = d.id;
            else
                result_data.emplace_back({.json_id = d.id, .latitude = d.latitude, .longitude = d.longitude});
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    // At this point, any point in result set that was in both the CSV and
    // JSON will have both IDs set.
    //
    // Any point found in the JSON that wasn't in the CSV was added with the
    // CSV ID as -1.
    //
    // And any point that was in the CSV but for which no JSON match was
    // found, it will still have the JSON ID as -1 from read_csv_data().

    return result_data;
}
```

And of course, writing the output is trivial:

```
auto write_results(std::ostream& out, std::vector<result_t> const& data)
{
    std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [&out](auto&& d)
    {
        out << d.csv_id << ':' << d.json_id << '\n';
    });
}
```

And you main function is also trivial:

```
auto const default_csv_path  = std::filesystem::path{input.csv"};
auto const default_json_path = std::filesystem::path{input.json"};

auto main(int argc, char* argv[]) -> int
{
    if (argc != 1 && argc != 3)
    {
        std::cerr << "Invalid arguments" << std::endl;
        // exit(1); // NEVER use exit() in C++. It doesnt't call destructors.

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    auto csv_path  = default_csv_path;
    auto json_path = default_json_path;

    if (argc == 3)
    {
        csv_path  = argv[1];
        json_path = argv[2];
    }

    auto data = read_csv_data(csv_path);

    data = read_json_data(json_path, std::move(data));

    write_result(std::cout, data);
}
```

That’s it!

## Summary

Get the types right. That will make a HUGE difference. It makes code easier to read, and it can make large differences in performance, too. You should’t really be trucking longitude and latitude around as strings… because they’re not strings, they’re numeric values.

Avoid allocations in loops. You also need to be aware of when functions are probably going to be called in loops. For example, a stream extractor for sensor data is pretty likely to be used in a loop that reads sensor data in from a file. Don’t prematurely optimize, but do ask yourself questions like: “do I *need* to make a vector of strings to parse this data… why can’t I just read the `double` values directly from the stream into the desired output type”?

Generally, consider what you really want. Do you want a vector of sensor data? Or… are you really after a collection of CSV IDs and JSON IDs? If the latter, perhaps there’s a way to get the best of both worlds, so you don’t need two large collections of data when you can get away with one.